# Google chrome extension to open the New Tab page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple chrome extension.
It is supposed to add an item "Open new tab" in the 'windows system tray chrome icon context menu' (similar to how the checker plus for gmail extension has done; see the second image given below).

when I click the option, chrome is supposed to *(check if any window is open. If yes, then it is supposed to)* open a new tab page. If no windows are open, then it is supposed to open a new chrome window with the new tab page showing.

What I have done till now:

### manifest.json

```
{  
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Open New Tab",  
  "description": "This extension open a new tab page",  
  "version": "1.0",  
  "browser_action": {  
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },  
  "background":{  
    "scripts":["background.js"],  
    "persistent": false
  },  
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

### background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)   
{  
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://newtab" });  
}
);
```

### background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(window)                         
{  
    chrome.windows.create({url: "chrome://newtab", type: "normal"});  
}
);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I have already loaded this extension.
The effects of my extension on chrome so far:
1) Chrome window is already open.
My icon shows up in the list of extensions and is clickable.[image]
 On clicking, a 'new tab' page is opened in the same window. This is correct. (Though I don't need this. For now, let it be.)

2) Chrome window is closed, and chrome is allowed to run in the background. Rightclick the chrome tray icon. My extension menu 'Open a new tab' shows up in the menu.[image]
This is also correct. On clicking it, a new chrome window is created. (Currently, I have not yet checked if a window already exists. That is to come later.).

The problem is that, in the new window that opens, instead of the 'new tab' page, chrome automatically opens the 'chrome://extensions' URL. This is wrong, and I cannot understand why the extensions page is opening. I want to open the new tab page, and i am passing the 'chrome://newtab' URL. How do I make chrome open the new tab page from here? Chrome works correctly when I start it from my desktop icon or windows start menu. So, the problem seems to be something with my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you mix extension icon with browser action, "Open New Tab" in your photo is not browser action, when you click "Open New Tab", actually the browser is launched rather than your `browser action` is executed.

Comment: I thought something like that. I mean 'browser_action' in itself means you need to have a browser window to click something...

What I want is to open the chrome window and display "New Tab" page when I click on the context menu as shown in the second image.
If Chrome is already open, I can use the square button to the right of tabs to open the new tab page anyway, so I don't need that browser action. But how do I specify the action for the "SYS_TRAY_ICON_CLICK... something" event in the manifest?

Comment: what about listenning to `chrome.windows.onCreated` event, when it is fired a new window is created, then you could call `chrome.tabs.create` to create a new tab.

Comment: hmm... Thats an idea... I'll try and report back.

Comment: @Haibara Ai
Thanks for your idea. Finally I got it working.

    chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) 
    {
     chrome.tabs.update(null, { url: "chrome://newtab" });
    });

Comment: Now, I want this to work only one time, that is, when there are no windows open(maximized, or minimized), and chrome is running in the background and its system tray icon is visible. I right click the icon, and select my menu. The new window pops up. Everything till here is fine, but somehow, it also interferes with other webpages and sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to `chrome.windows.onCreated` event, when right clicking chrome tray icon, a new window would be launched, then you could create a new tab in the event handler.

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(window) {
    chrome.windows.getAll(function(windows) {
        if (windows.length === 1) {           
            chrome.tabs.create({windowId: window.id, url: "chrome://newtab"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now, I want this to work only one time, that is, when there are no windows open(maximized, or minimized), and chrome is running in the background and its system tray icon is visible. I right click the icon, and select my menu. The new window pops up. Everything till here is fine,

Comment: But somehow, it also interferes with other webpages and sites. As an example, I use Feedly.com as my main news reader. When I open Feedly, it asks me to login. The login page opens up as a new window/tab. This new window/tab creation event also gets caught by my extension, and it converts the feedly login page to a NewTab page!!!

So, how do I restrict my extension only to work when there are no chrome windows?

Should I ask this as a new question?

Comment: @PRinCEKtd, take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll , you could get window count and do a check before creating a new tab.

Comment: Thanks for the link.